# Are DOM events cleared when iframe src is changed?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, iframe

I have a html page with an iframe and would like to switch the content using the src attribute.  The iframe content may contain JQuery and Angular.  If I change the src attribute, are the DOM events (JQuery and Angular resources) in the iframe cleared before the new iframe content is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "DOM Events" you mean DOM event handlers, then yes they are cleared.

DOM event handlers are attached to specific DOM elements.  When those DOM elements are replaced, all the event handlers will be gone too.  And, setting the `.src` of an iframe will replace all the DOM elements in the iframe so thus all prior event handlers will be gone too.

In fact, replacing the `.src` of an iframe is essentially loading a whole new page so the entire Javascript context is replaced and built anew.  Nothing from the prior page survives.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The iframe's window's entire environment is wiped and replaced with a new one for the new page. That includes the JavaScript environment and everything in it — global variables, declared functions, loaded scripts, etc. — and the complete DOM structure, and thus any event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes those events gets cleared, Because when you change the `src` of `iframe`, Iframe loads that URL content & create a new `window`/`document` which don't has initially binded event. Basically it like the fresh DOM.